# Using ExtraParams in C# to pull specific events from Stripe's API

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

So, I feel like I am overlooking something incredibly simple.  I am currently trying to pull all charge events for a single card given the card fingerprint from Stripe.  However, I am pretty lost on how to do so without also supplying a customer ID, though I think I am close.  I don't want to supply a customer ID since the purpose of this is to see who has been attempting to use the card.  Please point out the error of my ways because I can't find any documentation anywhere that suggests what I am doing wrong.  It's a lot of payment processing examples, no filtering like I'm trying to do, and the API documentation doesn't explain how to filter "deeper".

Here's the function I am currently using:

```
private StripeList<Charge> GetCardCharges(string card_id)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "source.fingerprint", card_id } };
            ChargeListOptions options = new ChargeListOptions { Limit = 100, ExtraParams = dict, };
            var service = new ChargeService();
            var charges = service.List(options);
            return charges;
        }
```

I have even tried

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "source", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "fingerprint", card_id } } } };
```

and have used an IDictionary instead and I still keep getting an unknown parameter message.  Without the extra parameters it works fine in that it pulls 100 charge events, but that isn't very useful to me and writing a function that looks at every charge event ever seems inefficient.  I am of course able to successfully filter from the "initial level" parameters in the JSON object, such as:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "amount_refunded", 0 } };
```

I thank you in advanced for at least reading over this, and let me know if more information is needed!  Here's a charge event from the test data for reference:

```
<Stripe.Charge@26602077 id=ch_1Hnzaj2eZvKYlo2CYBG4aWb4> JSON: {
  "id": "ch_1Hnzaj2eZvKYlo2CYBG4aWb4",
  "object": "charge",
  "amount": 100,
  "amount_captured": 0,
  "amount_refunded": 0,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee": null,
  "application_fee_amount": null,
  "authorization_code": null,
  "balance_transaction": null,
  "billing_details": {
    "address": {
      "city": null,
      "country": null,
      "line1": null,
      "line2": null,
      "postal_code": null,
      "state": null
    },
    "email": null,
    "name": null,
    "phone": null
  },
  "calculated_statement_descriptor": null,
  "captured": false,
  "created": 1605501925,
  "currency": "usd",
  "customer": null,
  "description": "My First Test Charge (created for API docs)",
  "destination": null,
  "dispute": null,
  "disputed": false,
  "failure_code": null,
  "failure_message": null,
  "fraud_details": {
    "stripe_report": null,
    "user_report": null
  },
  "invoice": null,
  "level3": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "order": null,
  "outcome": null,
  "paid": true,
  "payment_intent": null,
  "payment_method": "pm_1Hnzae2eZvKYlo2CZvrXwBjh",
  "payment_method_details": {
    "ach_credit_transfer": null,
    "ach_debit": null,
    "acss_debit": null,
    "alipay": null,
    "au_becs_debit": null,
    "bacs_debit": null,
    "bancontact": null,
    "card": {
      "brand": "visa",
      "checks": {
        "address_line1_check": null,
        "address_postal_code_check": null,
        "cvc_check": "pass"
      },
      "country": "US",
      "description": null,
      "exp_month": 8,
      "exp_year": 2021,
      "fingerprint": "Xt5EWLLDS7FJjR1c",
      "funding": "credit",
      "iin": null,
      "installments": null,
      "issuer": null,
      "last4": "4242",
      "moto": null,
      "network": "visa",
      "three_d_secure": null,
      "wallet": null
    },
    "card_present": null,
    "eps": null,
    "fpx": null,
    "giropay": null,
    "ideal": null,
    "interac_present": null,
    "klarna": null,
    "multibanco": null,
    "oxxo": null,
    "p24": null,
    "sepa_debit": null,
    "stripe_account": null,
    "type": "card",
    "wechat": null
  },
  "receipt_email": null,
  "receipt_number": null,
  "receipt_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1032D82eZvKYlo2C/ch_1Hnzaj2eZvKYlo2CYBG4aWb4/rcpt_IOnBY5JhICLngxEzCsH1wb609egY5bR",
  "refunded": false,
  "refunds": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [],
    "has_more": false,
    "url": "/v1/charges/ch_1Hnzaj2eZvKYlo2CYBG4aWb4/refunds"
  },
  "review": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "source": {
    "id": "card_1Hnzae2eZvKYlo2CYAmFdjYF",
    "object": "card",
    "account": null,
    "address_city": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": null,
    "address_zip_check": null,
    "available_payout_methods": null,
    "brand": "Visa",
    "country": "US",
    "currency": null,
    "customer": null,
    "cvc_check": "pass",
    "default_for_currency": null,
    "description": null,
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "exp_month": 8,
    "exp_year": 2021,
    "fingerprint": "Xt5EWLLDS7FJjR1c",
    "funding": "credit",
    "iin": null,
    "issuer": null,
    "last4": "4242",
    "metadata": {},
    "name": null,
    "tokenization_method": null
  },
  "source_transfer": null,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
  "status": "succeeded",
  "transfer": null,
  "transfer_data": null,
  "transfer_group": null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ExtraParams` is used to pass in parameters that aren't available natively in the SDK. The main use case is for beta features that haven't made it into the SDK yet.

You can't use `ExtraParams` to filter on a specific parameter in a List endpoint, your only options are what's documented in the API ref: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list

In your case you'd have to list all Charges and filter them yourself by looking at [`charge.payment_method_details.card.fingerprint`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-payment_method_details-card-fingerprint)

Comment: Thank you for that!  Just to make sure I understand, I would need to gather all events and then filter after that?  Probably using Linq at that point after adequate conversion?  I don't want continuous calls for everything just to then comb through it all.  Parsing JSON isn't the issue, it's that there are millions of events I'd need to sort through each time there is a call to the function if that's the case.  If not possible then fair, but I want to make sure.  I understand the Dashboard search function operates differently than the C# API.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do really. If you want to get all charges made with a specific card fingerprint, then you'd have to pull the entire list of charges from the API and then loop over the results, checking the parameter I linked to earlier. An alternative would be to use Stripe Sigma: https://stripe.com/sigma